# Pandas appears to fail silently when reading tab-delimited text file

Tags: python, pandas

I have a tab-delimited text file with 127294 lines (including header), but when I attempt to read it into a pandas dataframe, the result only has 126674 rows (619 fewer rows than expected).

There is no error message / exception or warning.  The correct number of columns are present.

I'm reading it in with:

```
df = pandas.read_csv("temp", sep="\t")
```

Answer (score 1):

I discovered that there are 2 double quote (") characters in the file separated by 619 lines.  Pandas by default treats the quote as enclosing an entry so it includes all tabs and newlines in that entry until it reaches the next quote.

I was able to read the file as I wanted (with correct # of rows) with:

```
df = pandas.read_csv("temp", sep="\t", quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE)
```

Alternatively I could have edited the file to surround that entry with single quotes etc. if it were important to allow quoting in the file.